# C, Static library, linker: How to give preference to strong symbol over weak symbol

Tags: c, gcc, linker, static-libraries

I have a strong symbol in an object file and a weak symbol in a static library.

If I compile without putting the object file in another library, strong symbol is selected.

```
gcc q_htb.o -lresolv -L. -lasntc -lnetlink -lutil -L. -lm -o tc
```

Here q_htb.o contains the strong symbol `htb_qdisc_uti` and libasntc library contains the weak symbol.

```
 nm tc | grep htb_qdisc_util
0000000000615960 D htb_qdisc_util
```

Now, if I put q_htb.o object file in a static library `libhtb`, preference is given to weak symbol

```
gcc -lresolv -L. -lasntc -lhtb -lnetlink -lutil -L. -lm -o tc
nm tc | grep htb_qdisc_util
                 w htb_qdisc_util
```

As shown above, `htb_qdisc_util` is weak. I need to have q_htb.o in a static library, How do I make select the strong symbol?

Note: Changing the order of the library did not help.

EDIT:

Strong symbol definiation in q_htb.o, contains just q_htb.c

```
struct qdisc_util htb_qdisc_util = {
    .id         = "htb",
    .parse_qopt = htb_parse_opt,
    .print_qopt = htb_print_opt,
    .print_xstats   = htb_print_xstats,
    .parse_copt = htb_parse_class_opt,
    .print_copt = htb_print_opt,
};
```

Weak symbol in libasntc.a

```
 extern char htb_qdisc_util[] __attribute__((weak)); if (!strcmp(sym, "htb_qdisc_util")) return htb_qdisc_util;
```

Answer (score 0):

Files in libraries(I.e. `q_htb.o`) are either fully added, or not at all. So if the weak symbol can be in a .o file with no other symbols, it won't be pulled in